# rails sums model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have a lot of sum functions in my app.  I am moving all data sums to a separate model...lets call it...sums.  This will make calling those numbers faster as I wont nail the database everytime I need to sum many rows.

What I would like to do is update the sum row (many attributes) each time certain other models are created or updated.  I am trying to this via each model using a class method but for some reason its not working.

Im wondering where I can create a universal method that can be called from an after_create callback for whichever models I choose.  The sum is associated to an account, which is not the model being updated.  Other account associated models are the ones that will hit the sums model. Therefor, I will probably need to pass self.account_id to the callback method.

Like Papertrails versions model, that is updated everytime another model is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Statistics](https://github.com/acatighera/statistics) gem.

It has a cache option that uses Rails cache to prevent repeated aggregation calls to database.

I would prefer something like this as opposed to have an update every time a property gets updated. If you are not planning to hold the `sums` model in memory, then you will have to fire as many updates to `sums` table as there are actual updates.

While it may be OK to have write-time overheads, as opposed to read-time, Statistics comes with other options to optimize.

Comment: Looks great.  Ill try it.  I guess if the gem is caching then it a better option than using a separate table.  The gem hasn't been updated in a looong time...are there any newer/better options?

Comment: Do you know if you can use statistics with associations?  @user.accounts.statistics(count: :all).  I have a lot of helpers that do counts or sums...like, @rating.flights.sum(:xc).  Will using the statics gem make these sums and counts more efficient?

Comment: [this example](https://github.com/acatighera/statistics#reuse-scopes-you-already-have-defined) uses statistics on a `has_many` association. Is that what you are after? As for efficiency, I'm afraid I can't generalize, it is quite subjective. I've not had any performance complaints so far.